# LINQ to SQL querying across relationships

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq

This is driving me mad. I thought it seemed simple enough but the below is returning a list of `IEnumerable` containing the entities I need, instead of just a list of entities:

```
db.tblPeople.Where(p => p.id == id).Select(s => s.tblCars.Select(z => z.tblCarType)).ToList();
```

My attempt is to retrieve a list of all `carType` entities associated with the `personId`.

I assume it's something to do with the last nested `select`?

Comment: What do you get, and what do you want to get? :)

Comment: Sorry, updated the Q.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx) in order to flatten `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<CarType>>` into `IEnumerable<CarType>`.

```
var carTypes =
    db.tblPeople
      .Where(p => p.id == id)
      .SelectMany(s =>
          s.tblCars
           .Select(z => z.tblCarType))
      .ToList();
```

This translates from

```
var carTypes =
    (from person in tblPeople
     from car in person.tblCar
     from carType in car.tblCarType
     where person.id == id
     select carType).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for the translation, I didn't know you could just simply chain `from` references like that!

Comment: Yes you can chain from clauses which a lot of parser combinator libraries like [Sprache](https://github.com/sprache/Sprache) use to have a nice declarative syntax.

Answer (score 3):

Do like this because you are expecting multiple records to be returned:

```
 var result =   db.tblPeople
                  .Where(p => p.id == id)
                  .Select(s => s.tblCars
                  .SelectMany(z => z.tblCarType)).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you this worked. I noticed you swapped the `Select` and `SelectMany` method calls, which originally did not work.

Comment: It was correct when you first swapped it selectmany then select :)

Comment: yes i thought it must be this way then i got confused

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want/need:

db.tblPeople.Where(p => p.id == id).**SelectMany**(s => s.tblCars.Select(z => z.tblCarType)).ToList();

Comment: It only works for me if `SelectMany` is before the final `Select`